# How to handle Hive Unequal Partitions

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I have customer sales data by partitioned by state/province in Hive , but some province partitions are having huge data where sales is high where as some province partitions is having less data .
How to handle the scenario for faster execution / optimization .

Comment: What execution engine your Hive is using?

Comment: Hive engine has been kept to default - MR .

Comment: @MaheshKhatai did you find any solution for this?